# Return custom results using the Aggregate framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've the following Schemas in my Node.js app:

```
let CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({        
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        firstName: { type: String, required: true },
        lastName: { type: String, required: true }
});

let CustomerSchema = mongoose.Schema({        
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

let VendorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    category: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }],
    products: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' } ],
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

let ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({        
        vendorID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vendor' },
        name: { type: String, index: true, required: true },      
        customerReviews: [{
            stars: { type: Number, required: false },
            review: { type: String, required: false },
            customerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer', required: true }
        }]
});
```

and I am trying to query the Vendors collection to  return the following result:

```
{
    _id: "dsi9dsik129dkdsdsds",
    userData: {
    _id: "dsa9dskd2kwd29dkkss",
    firstName: "Michael",
    lastName: "White"
    },
    categoryData: {
    _id: "e9dids91i239dskds91",
    name: "Category A"
    },
    productsData: [ {
    _id: "3132139i31j32131",
    vendorID: "dsi9dsik129dkdsdsds",
    name: "Product ABC",
    customerReviews [{
        stars: "5",
            review: "Good",
        customerData: {
        _id: "zds91i232131j2321j",
        name: "John silver"
        }
    },
    {
        stars: "3",
            review: "Bad",
        customerData: {
        _id: "ldso91232131j2321j",
        name: "Mark Spenser"
        }
    }]
    } ],
    name: "Vendor XYZ"
}
```

I've built the following query on **Vendors** collection (meaning Vendors.aggregate(...) ) yet I am not sure how to format the returned results as well as retrieve Customers data in customers review, so I was wondering if anyone can help? Thanks.

```
(
 { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "userID", foreignField: "_id", as: "userData"  } },
 { $lookup: { from: "categories", localField: "category", foreignField: "_id", as: "categoryData"  } },
 { $lookup: { from: "products", localField: "products", foreignField: "_id", as: "productsData"  } },
 { $group: { _id: null, content: { $push: '$$ROOT' },count: { $sum: 1 } } },
 { $project: { content: { $slice: [ '$content', 0, 10 ] }, count: 1, _id: 0 } },
)
```

Test:

```
Category:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de7fc530ce9d05be4024170"),
    "categoryName" : "Glass",
    "__v" : 0
}

User:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6671ae7be3be4e18ebe9bb"),
    "firstName" : "Mark",
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "__v" : 0
}

Customer:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd7cb11f4b2544253368f24"),
    "customerName" : "Michael White",
    "__v" : 0
}

Vendor:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de7fc6a0ce9d05be4024171"),
    "category" : [ 
        ObjectId("5de7fc530ce9d05be4024170")
    ],
    "products" : [ 
        ObjectId("5de8474ccd0bbc05256db819")
    ],
    "userID" : ObjectId("5d6671ae7be3be4e18ebe9bb"),
    "vendorName" : "Michael White",
    "__v" : 0
}

Product:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de8474ccd0bbc05256db819"),
    "vendorID" : ObjectId("5de7fc6a0ce9d05be4024171"),
    "name" : "Red Sause",
    "customerReviews" : [ 
        {
            "moderated" : false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5de7fcf20ce9d05be4024175"),
            "customerId" : ObjectId("5dd7cb11f4b2544253368f24"),
            "stars" : 3,
            "review" : "Didn't like it that much :( ",
            "date" : ISODate("2019-12-04T18:37:38.253Z")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Note: I've added entity name before name in the test above, ex. vendorName / customerName just to avoid confusion between the field 'name' across multiple collections

Comment: could you please add some test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation from 3.6 version.

```
{"$lookup":{ 
    "from": "users", 
    "localField": "userID", 
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "userData"  
}},
{"$unwind":"$userData"},
{"$lookup":{ 
    "from": "categories", 
    "localField": "category", 
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "categoryData"  
}},
{"$lookup":{ 
   "from":"products",
   "let":{"products":"$products"},
   "pipeline":[
     {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$_id","$$products"]}}},
     {"$unwind":{"path":"$customerReviews", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},         
     {"$lookup":{
      "from":"customers",
      "localField":"customerReviews.customerId",
      "foreignField":"_id",
      "as":"customerData"
     }},
    {"$unwind":{"path":"$customerData", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}}, 
    {"$group":{
      "_id":"$_id",
      "vendorID": {"$first":"$vendorID"},
      "name": {"$first":"$name"},
      "customerReviews":{
         "$push":{ 
           "stars": "$customerReviews.stars",
           "review": "$customerReviews.review",
           "customerData":"$customerData"
          }
        }
     }}
  ],
  "as":"productsData"
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, categoryData and userData are returned perfectly, but products are always returned empty, so I was wondering if I am missing anything here? Thanks

Comment: Np. I can't say anything without the test data. can you update the post to include your testing data ?

Comment: I've edited the question, added some test data. I've also added prefix entity name to 'name' fields to avoid confusion between the name fields across different collections. Thanks again for your time and efforts.

Comment: Np. Just verified. I can see the product data for the sample data you posted. It could be you don't have customer reviews for some products. You could try  `"preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true` option for `$unwind` to keep the row when they are empty or missing. Updated answer.. Also please verify the collection names are correct in the query.